# TypeORM remove OneToMany composite primary key getting violating null contraint

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a relation of `Teams -> TeamMembers`.

When I try to update a team's members I am calling:

```js
await this.teamsRepo
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .relation(Team, 'members')
    .of(teamLeaderTeam)
    .addAndRemove(leaders, teamLeaderTeam.members);
```

teamLeaderTeam is of type `Team` and leaders is of type `{ userId: number, teamId: number, level: MemberLevel}[]`.

However, when I call that I always get this following error: `QueryFailedError: null value in column "teamId" of relation "team_member" violates not-null constraint` from the `.remove()`.

I don't know what TypeORM is setting the relation to null instead of just deleting it. Upon further inspection of QueryFailedError I can see this it the fault: `Failing row contains (null, 39, Intermediate).`.

**Team:**

```js
@Entity()
@Tree('materialized-path')
export class Team {
    /**
     * The teams's unique ID
     */
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ unsigned: true })
    id!: number;

    ...

    /**
     * The members belonging to the team
     */
    @OneToMany(() => TeamMember, teamMember => teamMember.team, { cascade: true })
    members!: TeamMember[];
}
```

**Team Member:**

```js
@Entity()
export class TeamMember {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    teamId: number;

    /**
     * The team this member belongs to
     */
    @ManyToOne(() => Team, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    team!: Team;

    @PrimaryColumn()
    userId: number;

    /**
     * The user who belongs to the team
     */
    @ManyToOne(() => User, { eager: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    user: User;

    /**
     * The level of membership this user has in the team
     */
    @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: MemberLevel })
    level!: MemberLevel;
}
```

Comment: If you still have this code maybe the `orphanedRowAction` option could help on the `@OneToMany` ?

Comment: PS: Sorry, I mean the `@ManyToOne` decoration